# TFS performance issues with data tier on Hyper-V

Tags: sql-server, performance, tfs, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

Since I want to evaluate TFS 2018 as a solution for our 25 Person Dev Team, I installed an evaluation alongside with the SQL Server 2017 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 (running on a physical Win Server 2012 R2).

The problem (**TLDR**): **The only time when TFS perform fast is when connecting remotely to the server and login with just one account.  As soon as a second user logs into the TFS web interface, the response time increases up to 2-3 minutes for everything. Any domain network login causes also the response performance to drop.**

VM Specs:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- TFS 2018 app & data tier
- SQL Server 2017 (only for TFS)
- IIS (only for TFS)
- The VM has assigned 4 Threads (2 Cores)
- 2-32 GB Dynamic Memory (25% buffer) usually taking about 8GB
- Connection via SSL

Physical Specs:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Roles: Domain Controller, Active Directory, DNS, WSUS, CertAuth, Hyper-V (only running the TFS Machine above), Repository Server
- Xeon E5-2620 @ 2.1GHz
- Physical RAID 5 with 3 disks (7200rpm).
- 4x16 GB RAM (own channel each)

Details:

Ok, I know that the physical server already performs quite a load of a task, but we have just a small network of about 30 Workstations. I noticed no significant performance issues since the Hyper-V / TFS installation.

I know that putting the data tier (SQL Server) also in the VM is not recommended since the overhead of the host system will most likely slow down any I/O. But I don't have the feeling it is a hardware problem, since there a no repository in there jet, and it's responding fast if just one user accesses it. I'll probably get an appropriate physical server for the data tier once it will be used in a production environment, but for now, I just want to evaluate the capabilities of TFS if it fits our workflow needs.

We authenticate via Active Directory and SSL properly certified from the physical host.

Ping goes through in < 1 ms so no network load issues.

The resource monitor (both VM and physical) are barely different to idle during requests.

Installing TFS with and SQL Server Express on a local machine works just fine as you would expect.

I feel like I read every tutorial and guide about TFS, installing SQL Server on Hyper-V Servers, troubleshoot performance issues with TFS and so on.

I sitting on this problem for weeks now and don't find a cause of this problem.

Has anyone an idea what could cause this issue or what I could look into?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 is in the works - so which one are you **really** using??

Comment: You are correct, SQL Server 2017 is installed! Thank you for pointing that out.